# Handling Convertions

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

In vb:

```
Dim mEmpLeaves As EmployeeLeaves
mEmpLeaves = EmployeeLeaves.GetEmployeeLeaves(Session("DbConnector"), 
              "dbo.usp_EmployeeWebLeave" & EmployeeId)
ViewState("Empleave") = mEmpLeaves
```

in a diff function i use this viewstate like :

```
Dim mEmployeeLeaves As EmployeeLeaves = DirectCast(ViewState("Empleave"), 
                                    EmployeeLeaves)
Dim mEmployeeLeave As EmployeeLeave = 
                             mEmployeeLeaves.GetEmployeeLeaveById(leaveId)
```

Since I am not using viewstate in my API due to its stateless behaviour and which I have heard is not correct either. How can I achieve this?

What i am doing is

```
EmployeeLeaves mEmployeeLeaves = DbEntities.Usp_EmployeeWebLeave(EmployeeId)
                                 .FirstOrDefault();
mEmployeeLeave mEmployeeLeave= mEmployeeLeaves.GetEmployeeLeaveById(LeaveId)
```

also tried:

```
object Leaves = DbEntities.Usp_EmployeeWebLeave(EmployeeId)
                                 .FirstOrDefault();
EmployeeLeaves mEmployeeLeaves = (EmployeeLeaves)Leaves;
EmployeeLeave mEmployeeLeave= mEmployeeLeaves.GetEmployeeLeaveById(LeaveId);
```

I am getting a exception 
"

> Unable to cast object type
>   'employeeDataAccess.payCare.usp_EmployeeWebLeave_Result' to type
>   'HumanResource.Paycare.EmployeeLeaves

.

I am not finding a way to cast this. In such scenario vb seems to be so simple. Wasted my whole day behind this. Please if anyone can remove me out of this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will have to do that manually, because they are different types

Comment: @CodeNameJack : Can you please explain me that in detail ?

Comment: The result you are getting is usp_EmployeeWebLeave_Result type but you are assigning to HumanResource.Paycare.EmployeeLeaves.Even if they have same members, they still are different types

Comment: Please post `employeeDataAccess.payCare.usp_EmployeeWebLeave_Result` class and  `HumanResource.Paycare.EmployeeLeaves` class

Comment: @CodeNameJack : Yeah i understand that. But what did you mean by doing it manually?

Comment: doing it manually means you should map each field.I will better post in answer

Comment: @Sumitraj : They contain same members bro. In EmployeeLeaves they are doing nothing but calling the same stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Since both of them are different types, They should be mapped manually,

```
var Leaves = DbEntities.Usp_EmployeeWebLeave(EmployeeId)
                             .FirstOrDefault();
EmployeeLeaves mEmployeeLeaves=Converter(Leaves)






EmployeeLeaves Converter(usp_EmployeeWebLeave_Result e)
{
   return new
             HumanResource.Paycare.EmployeeLeaves(){
                   Name=leaves.Name,
                   Age=leaves.Age
                   ...........
          }   ;
}
```

Comment: so i do this for 30 properties which this EmployeeLeaves class contain.? There's no other way out by which i can cast this class ?

Comment: You create a method to do this, and call the conversation for each employee.